# adding foreach inside razor broke if else statement block of code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
@if (@Model.Persons.Count > 0)

    var data= @Model.Persons;
}
else
{
    <b>no data!</b>
}
```

when I add foreach statement inside if statement else block of code become broken

```
@if (@Model.Persons.Count > 0)
{        
    var data= @Model.Persons;
    foreach(var item in @data){
       ...
    }
}
else{ // this now becomes broken after adding foreach 
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@` from data in the foreach line?

Comment: I think that when you're using a `@if` or a tag like a @foreach (these kind of helpers), when you got a block with brackets just below it, you're in c# code, so the `@` befor Model and especially here, befor data, is useless. Try it !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `@` from `Model.Persons.Count`, from `Model.Persons` and from `data`.
You already created a block using the `@if (){ }`.

```
@if (Model.Persons.Count > 0)
{        
    var data= Model.Persons;
    foreach(var item in data){
      ...
    }
}
else
{
}
```